# Evaluating undefined variables as strings in Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I am trying to evaluate a list of comma separated values, where the strings are not surrounded by quotes, for example:

```
list = [54, 25, 1, 3467, 9, 45, 69, 420, 45, 65987, bob, 0, -5, 47.2, john, y]
```

Python obviously wants to parse the items [bob], [john], and [y] as variables. Since they are undefined, Python will throw a traceback error.

Is it possible to convert those items to strings when, or before the error occurs?

Comment: Why? This will just lead to confusing code. Just add the quotes.

Comment: Yes it's possible but how was the list generated? You want to solve this problem upstream before it occurs not provide a hacky fix now!

Comment: To be honest I cannot think of **any** way to do this. Mind showing it @Chris_Rands?

Comment: If you're trying to execute that line of code exactly as written, then no, it's not possible.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis why do you think it’s impossible to parse? Assuming the input is a string then it can be parsed although not elegantly I guess

Comment: I don't understand this question - if it's a CSV then the values parsing in *should* be all strings instead of the monstrosity as exampled.  If it's not, I echo @Chris_Rands's comment, just fix it upstream before it hits your code.  I think this is a classic XY problem.

Comment: @Chris_Rands because I'm not sure we can assume the input is a string. It's hard to say what the OP is trying to do

Comment: What, *exactly* are you trying to do here? Is this source code?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what else could the input be? if it's from a file or `input()` then it's a string, and it's not a valid Python object to `pickle` or anything

Comment: @Chris_Rands I have no idea. I fear that the OP is talking about *source code*, not data. In any event, there is insufficient detail in the question to know what is going on...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Unlikely I think, but how about something perverse like this ;) https://pastebin.com/frqaW0M6

Comment: @Chris_Rands Heh, yeah quite perverse, although it wouldn't work, `eval`ing single lines will often fail for valid Python code. Anyway, we'll have to wait and see what OP says

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga indeed, but once one `read`s in the source code as a string, it can ultimately be parsed one way or another. Perhaps there is a cleverer way to inspect the actual traceback? Anyway, pretty sure the OP won't say anything now, and this has become entirely academic...

Comment: @Chris_Rands If you can quote the list it becomes trivial but if you **can** quote you might as well quote the *variables* instead. I mean without any quoting.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

These are not a commas separated values, and this is not a list. There is a difference between data and source code. If `bob` etc. were defined, then running this would *generate* a list (and the commas would be just part of the formatting when printing the list, not actually part of the list), but as it is, it's just text in an editor. Phrases such as "convert to strings" apply to data, not source code. If you want to manipulate this, then you have to treat it as data. So, for instance, if you were to add quote marks, you can do:

```
list_string =  '[54, 25, 1, 3467, 9, 45, 69, 420, 45, 65987, bob, 0, -5, 47.2, john, y]'
list_from_string = list_string.replace('[','').replace(']','').split(', ')
for index,item in enumerate(list_from_string):
    try:
        item_as_int = int(item)
        item_as_float = float(item)
        if item_as_int == item_as_float:
            list_from_string[index] = item_as_int
        else:
            list_from_string[index] = item_as_float
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score -3):

Naive Solution:

I would suggest making it a string as @Carcigenicate suggested and splitting it using comma if you want to extract values in the list.

```
my_list = '[54, 25, 1, 3467, 9, 45, 69, 420, 45, 65987, bob, 0, -5, 47.2, john, y]'

my_list = my_list.strip('[]')  # This will strip square brackeets from both ends
my_list.split(', ')  # since your input is comma and space separated list
['54', '25', '1', '3467', '9', '45', '69', '420', '45', '65987', 'bob', '0', '-5', '47.2', 'john', 'y']
```

Does this help you?